# Creating a promotion that starts at 9am for all stores worldwide

Tags: javascript, java, date, time, timezone

Let's say, for example, that a store promotion starts at 9am for all stores worldwide. This means that it starts at 9am CST for stores in Chicago, 9am PST for stores in Seattle, and 9am GMT for stores in the UK.

In our `promotions` table on Postgres, we would set the start time for this promotion as 09:00:00.

Each store has a computer with a web browser that looks up available promotions. It needs to pass its local time to the server so that the server can return all promotions for that local time. Thus we need to find a way to capture the local time in JavaScript, encode it, send it to a Java backend, reconstruct it, and then compare that with the start time in the `promotions` table.

The local time, of course, depends on the time zone. If it's 9am in Chicago then a store in Chicago should tell the server that it's 9am. It's futile to send the UTC time without some indication of the time zone.

**Question:** What's a good way to capture the local time (based on time zone) in JavaScript, encode  that, send it to a Java backend, reconstruct it as a Java `Date`, and then compare that Java `Date` with the 9am promotion start time in the Postgres database?

**My (unsatisfactory) approach:** The best I can think of is to send the UTC time in milliseconds using JavaScript's `Date.getTime` method, along with the time zone offset, which can be calculated in minutes using JavaScript's `Date.getTimezoneOffset` method and converted to milliseconds. Subtracting the time zone offset from the UTC time in milliseconds, we can then create a Java `Date` object from the resulting difference. If it's 9am in Chicago, then, hopefully, the Java `Date` will store 9am. What's a little odd about this approach, however, is that the Java `Date` will actually be storing 9am UTC, even though it's representing 9am CST. This is just one of the reasons why I am not satisfied with this approach. Can you think of something better?

Comment: Why are you using `j.u.Date`? It's been as-good-as-deprecated for like 4 years. You want [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Comment: @Michael Because our software is at least five years old :) I know... `java.time` is the new standard... but unfortunately we're not using that in this part of code.

Comment: That's not an excuse. Use the ThreeTen-Backport or Joda Time, or upgrade to Java 8.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to encode an ISO 8601 string without UTC offset and send it to the server. Don’t know how that would work in Javascript, though. But you would avoid the “lying about the time” that you describe and is certainly worth avoiding.

Comment: @Michael But even if we were using java.time, how would that lead to a satisfactory solution?

Comment: @ktm5124 Because LocalDateTime represents a date time without a zone, which is exactly what you want. `j.u.Date` is zoned to UTC.

Comment: @Michael I see. From the Java-side, it makes sense to use `LocalDateTime` if possible. What about from the JavaScript side? The best I could think of was to use `getTimezoneOffset`, convert it to milliseconds, and subtract it from the UTC time in milliseconds... not too happy about this approach, though, to be honest.

Comment: [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Postgres

In Postgres, when you mean 9 AM everywhere, or 9 AM anywhere, on a certain date, use the column data type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Any time zone or offset-from-UTC included with an input is ignored, with the date and time-of-day taken as-is (no adjustment) and stored. This data type purposely lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

For time-of-day without a date, use `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` data type. Postgres also offers a `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` only because it is required by the SQL spec; this `WITH` type is nonsensical and should never be used.

Postgres is an excellent choice for such a project, as it offers excellent date-time support in both [its data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) and in [its functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). Databases vary widely in their date-time features.

## Java

On the Java backend, use only the modern *java.time* classes. These years ago supplanted the *terrible* old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

If not yet using Java 8 or later, find nearly all the same functionality in a back-port to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Well worth the minor effort of adding this library to your project. From the same fine folks who brought you the *java.time* classes and the Joda-Time project, all led by the same man Stephen Colebourne.

### `LocalDateTime`

In *java.time*, use `LocalDateTime` class for when you mean 9 AM anywhere/everywhere on a certain date. Like `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in Postgres, this class purposely lacks any concept of zone or offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 15 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;  // 3 PM on 23rd of January this year.
```

### `LocalTime`

If you mean the time-of-day only, without a date, use the class `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ;  // 3 PM.
```

### JDBC

As of JDBC 4.2 and later you can exchange *java.time* objects with the database via `getObject` and `setObject` methods.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

If your JDBC drivers are not yet updated to 4.2, then fall back to the awful old legacy classes, but convert immediately to the *java.time* classes.

Given that the legacy classes lack a class for a date plus time-of-day without time zone, we have to fake it. Use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) which represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds, and just ignore the fact that it is in UTC.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … ) ;
```

For Java 8 and later, convert using new methods added to the old classes. Convert first to [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), which also represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. Then convert to a `LocalDateTime` by effectively removing the concept of UTC.

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern one.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Remove the concept of UTC (or any other offset or zone) from our data.
```

For Java 6 & 7 using the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library, use the conversion methods in their utility [`DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class.

```
org.threeten.bp.Instant instant = org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toInstant( ts ) ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern.
org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Remove the concept of UTC (or any other offset or zone) from our data.
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

The `Local…` classes by definition have no real meaning until you place them in the context of a time zone. A `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment, does *not* represent a point on the timeline.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `PST` or  `BST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = 
    LocalDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.January , 23 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 9 , 0 ) 
    )
;

ZoneId zLosAngeles = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;  // Seattle time zone.
ZonedDateTime zdtSeattle = ldt.atZone( zLosAngeles ) ;

ZoneId zChicago = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = ldt.atZone( zChicago ) ;

ZoneId zLondon = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = ldt.atZone( zLondon ) ;
```

There we have three `ZonedDateTime` objects: `zdtSeattle`, `zdtChicago`, and `zdtLondon`. These are all 9 AM on the 23rd of January earlier this year. Understand that these are three very different moments, each being several hours earlier as you go eastward. They all have the same wall-clock time (9 AM on 23rd) but are three different points on the timeline.

## JavaScript

While I do not know JavaScript well enough to say for certain, I doubt you have any library there as rich for date-time handling. The *java.time* framework is industry-leading.

As for web client user-interface development, I use [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin), so it is a non-issue: pure Java on back-end auto-generates the HTML/CSS/DOM/JavaScript needed by the web browser.

> find a way to capture the local time in JavaScript

As for detecting the current default time zone in the client machine, I’m no expert, but as I recall the browsers do not return a named time zone, only an offset-from-UTC. See the [Answer by Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53417987/642706) for a possible solution. In any app (desktop or web), ultimately, if the correct time zone is vital, then you must ask or **confirm the desired/expected time zone with the user**. And it may be wise to always indicate somewhere on your user interface what time zone is being used by your app.

If you need to exchange date-time values between your Java backend and JavaScript code in the front-end, you have two choices primarily:

- ISO 8601
- Count-from-epoch

### ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a variety of textual formats for exchanging date-time values. These are wisely designed to avoid ambiguity. They are easy to parse by machine, and easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when generating/parsing strings.

### Count-from-Epoch

I do not recommend this approach, as it is confusing and error-prone, subject to ambiguity and incorrect assumptions between the people and libraries who are sending or receiving.

An [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) is a point in time used as baseline. Then some count forward or backward is made of some granularity.

One big problem is that there are [dozens of epoch references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) used by various systems. The *java.time* classes by default use the [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

Another problem is that there are many granularities such as whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds. Programmers must document/communicate clearly what granularity is in play.

If you were to be sending your three opening moments for your three stores to JavaScript as a count-from-epoch, you would be sending three different numbers.

```
long millisecondsSeattle = zdtSeattle.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
long millisecondsChicago = zdtChicago.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
long millisecondsLondon = zdtLondon.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

Results in three different numbers for three different moments.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Agree with all your points (as usual) except the recommendation for Vaadin to solve the JS side.  That is glossing over a key point in the question (IMHO).  See my answer about that part, and feel free to copy for your reference and future posts.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the feedback. I added a bit more of what little I know about JavaScript, and added a link to your Answer.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to capture the user's local time, but merely their IANA time zone identifier, such as `"America/Los_Angeles"`.  This can then be used in your Java back-end code in APIs that accept a time zone.

In most modern browsers, you can capture the the time zone id like this:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

If you require supporting older browsers, there are several libraries that will use this Intl API when available, but will fall back to an educated guess when not.  [More on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625076/634824).

Comment: Since we're stuck using java.util.Date, it might actually be hard to parse a Date from an IANA time zone identifier. Would you happen to know differently? I wish we could convert to java.time, but this is an old piece of code that still uses java.util.Date.

Comment: You wouldn't parse it to a `Date`, you'd use [`java.util.TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html), possibly in conjunction with [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and/or  [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  IANA time zone IDs are not unique to the new java.time APIs (though still, you should prefer those when possible).